# How to make Alexa run MySQL Querys through a skill

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, mysql-workbench, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to set up an alexa skill that calls MySQL Querys when a certain question gets asked. Nothing I tried seemed to work because I either get an error or nothing happens at all.

*I am using/what I am working with:*

- Alexa Developer Console
- Cloud9 as IDE(which uploads the code to AWS Lambda, where I defined the environmental variables used in my code)
- AWS Lambda, NodeJS
- Amazon RDS, which hosts my DB instance
- MySQL Workbench (where I created a few tables to test the database, which works fine)

I tried several ways to solve my problem, like creating a connection or a pool, but I think it has to be handled differently, because Alexa has to wait for the response.

```
const GetOeffnungszeiten_Handler =  {
canHandle(handlerInput) {
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    return request.type === 'IntentRequest' && request.intent.name === 'GetOeffnungszeiten' ;
},
handle(handlerInput) {
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    const responseBuilder = handlerInput.responseBuilder;
    let sessionAttributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();

    let say = 'OUTPUT: ';

    var mysql = require('mysql');
    var connection  = mysql.createPool({
        host     : process.env.MYSQL_HOSTNAME,
        user     : process.env.MYSQL_USERNAME,
        password : process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
        database : process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE,
        port     : process.env.MYSQL_PORT
});
exports.handler =  (event, context, callback) => {
context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
connection.query('select name from persons where id=1', function (error, results, fields) {
  connection.release();
  if (error) {
      callback(error);
    say=say+'0';
  } else {
      callback(null,results[0].name);
    say=say+' 1';
  }
        });
    });
};

    return responseBuilder
        .speak(say)
        .reprompt('try again, ' + say)
        .getResponse();
    },
};
```

I expect the output to either be "OUTPUT: 1" or "OUTPUT: 0" but it is "OUTPUT: "
With output I refer to the say variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is returning `responseBuilder...getResponse()` **before** the SQL connection finishes and `callback` is called.

I would suggest to refactor your code using `async` and `await` to make it easier to read and to understand. (read https://stormacq.com/2019/06/22/async-js.html for help)

Be sure to return the Alexa response only when your call to MySQL returns, and not before. Remember that Alexa timeout is 8 secs, so your code need to return before that.  Be sure that the AWS Lambda timeout is aligned to the Alexa timeout too (put it at 7 secs)

Finally, I would advise against using MySQL for Alexa skills.  Because each Lambda invocation might be served by different containers, your code will create a connection pool for each interaction between customers and your skill, creating a significant delay to bring a response to customers.  DynamoDB and Elastic Cache are much better suited to Alexa skills.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I know I ask for a lot but could you maybe show me how the SQL connection would work, using the code I provided? I will look into DynamoDB but for now, as I set up everything, I would still like to try it out with MySQL as all of this is just for testing purposes. Its not easy for me to adapt my code, since everything with alexa works with handler constants instead of functions. Thank you for your help.